# Android - what is the right way to implement a wizard with an animation between the steps

Tags: android, animation, view, android-activity, wizard

I'm building and Android app that needs to go through steps like a wizard.

*Current structure:*

At the moment I'm using one activity with separate views.xml for each step, then I'm using `setContentView(activeStep)` to display the active step.

I ran into some difficulties when trying to animate between the steps. I used the following code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(activeStep, null, false);
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_in));
setContentView(view);
```

*The result:* the first view was gone and the new one animated, not a smooth transition.

My goal is to animate both views, one slides out the other in.

Question: Is it possible to do it with my current structure (reminder: one activity, many views) or should I treat each step as a separate activity?

Comment: Have you thought about using ViewSwitcher instead? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM to see it and http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/android_dont_overlook_viewswitcher/ for help

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try and let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is more the one way of implementing step progress with animation, here is how I did it:

```
private static ViewAnimator viewAnimator;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewAnimator = new ViewAnimator(this);
        View step1 = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.step_1, null);
        View step2 = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.step_2, null);
        View step3 = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.step_3, null);
        viewAnimator.addView(step1);
        viewAnimator.addView(step2);
        viewAnimator.addView(step3);
        viewAnimator.setInAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_in);
        viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_out);
        setContentView(viewAnimator);
    }
```

then clicking a button I call `viewAnimator.showNext()` and `viewAnimator.showPrevious()`
ViewSwitcher was not good for my purpose, because it can hold only 2 views at a time

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to use one `Activity` and a few different `View` structures if each step in the process is related.

You probably shouldn't use `setContentView` to change views with each step. Instead, possibly `hide` or `unhide` each item, or move it off the screen.

Comment: I think I will go with the ViewSwitcher idea, but thanks for the reply